# How to use member functions with 4 values 2 variables?

Tags: c++

I am trying to us member functions to allow for 2 rational (fractions) numbers (4 values) to be entered and only use 2 variables in the member functions.  numerator & denominator.  Cannot seem to make this work.

with the code below I receive the following:  When I enter 1/2 & 1/4
and select "2" to add i receive numerator = 1 denominator=1 r.numerator=1 r.denominator=2

so it is capturing the 1/2 but not the 1/4  now when I print the variables out in the input function I get 1/2 and 1/4.  so I am confused why 1/2 gets loaded and passed to Add but not 1/4.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you!

The following is the code in its unfinished state but it does compile and run.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>


class Rational
{
    public:
        Rational();
        Rational(int numerator, int denominator);
        Rational Input();
        void Add(Rational r);
        void Subtract(Rational r);
        void Multiply(Rational r);
        void Divide(Rational r);
        void printRational();
        void printRationalAsDouble();
        Rational Reduction();


    private:
        int numerator, denominator;

};


Rational::Rational()
{  
numerator = 1;
denominator = 1;
}



Rational Rational::Input()
{
    Rational r;
    cout<<"Enter two fractions. The denominator cannot be 0."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter first numerator: "<<endl; cin >> numerator;
    cout<<"Enter first denominator: " <<endl; cin >> denominator;
        if (denominator == 0)
        {
        cout<<"Please enter a valid denominator: "<<endl; cin >> denominator;
        }
        cout<<"Enter second numerator: "<<endl; cin >> r.numerator;
        cout<<"Enter second denominator: "<<endl; cin >> r.denominator;
        if (r.denominator == 0)
        {
        cout<<"Please enter a valid denominator: "<<endl; cin >> r.denominator;
        }
    cout<<endl;
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << " " << r.numerator 
            << "/" << r.denominator <<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    return(r);
}

void Rational::Add(Rational r)
{
    Rational Result, x;
    Result.numerator = (numerator * r.denominator) + (r.numerator * denominator);
    Result.denominator = denominator * r.denominator;
    cout << "numerator:" << numerator << endl;
    cout << "denominator:" << denominator << endl;
    cout << "r.nuerator:" << r.numerator << endl;
    cout << "r.denominator:" << r.denominator << endl;
    Result.Reduction();
    Result.printRational();
    Result.printRationalAsDouble();
}

void Rational::Subtract(Rational r)
{
    Rational Result;
    Result.numerator = (numerator * r.numerator) - (r.numerator * denominator);
    Result.denominator = denominator * r.denominator;
    Result.Reduction();
    Result.printRational();
    Result.printRationalAsDouble();
}

void Rational::Multiply(Rational r)
{
    Rational Result;
    Result.numerator = numerator * r.numerator;
    Result.denominator = denominator * r.denominator;
    Result.Reduction();
    Result.printRational();
    Result.printRationalAsDouble();
}

void Rational::Divide(Rational r)
{
    Rational Result;
    Result.numerator = numerator * r.denominator;
    Result.denominator = denominator  * r.numerator;
    Result.Reduction();
    Result.printRational();
    Result.printRationalAsDouble();
} 

void Rational::printRational()
{
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << "     Decimal:";
}

void Rational::printRationalAsDouble()
{
    cout << (double) numerator / denominator << endl;
}

Rational Rational::Reduction()
{
    Rational Result;
    int largest;
    largest = numerator > denominator ? numerator : denominator;

    int gcd = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= largest; i++)

        if(numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)
        gcd = i;
    if(gcd != 0)
    {
        Result.numerator = (numerator /= gcd);
        Result.denominator = (denominator /= gcd);
    }
    return(Result);
}

int main()
{

    cout <<"*****************************************************************************"
   << endl;
    cout <<"* This program will add two fractions, subract two fractions,               *"
   << endl; //Intro message to the user
    cout <<"* multiply two imputed fractions, or divide two fractions.                  *"
  << endl;
    cout <<"*****************************************************************************"
  << endl;


    int choice = 0;
    Rational x, A, S, M, D;
    while(choice != 6)
    {
        cout << "1. Enter two fractions." <<endl;
        cout << "2. Add and display result." <<endl;
        cout << "3. Subtract and display result." <<endl;
        cout << "4. Multiply and display result." <<endl;
        cout << "5. Divide and display result." <<endl;
        cout << "6. Quit " <<endl;
        cout <<"Selection choice: "<<endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            x.Input();
        }

        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            A.Add(x);

        }

        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "#3";
        }

        else if(choice == 4)
        {
            cout << "#4";
        }

        else if(choice == 5)
        {
            cout << "#5";
        }
    }     
return(0);
}
```

Comment: So, where's the definition for your `Rational::Rational()`. How come you consciously decided to *declare* it, yet provided no definition for it?

Comment: I also see you are a new user and that this is your first question, so please check out this topic:  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept the answer that is the best solution to your problem. If you have a new problem once this one is solved, go ahead and make a new post.

Comment: Will do thank you Joseph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never created a default constructor. You have a constructor that takes arguments, but you need to prototype and implement `Rational::Rational()`.

Something like this is what you'd want:

```
Rational::Rational() {
    numerator=1
    denominator=1
}
```

Or whatever values you see fit when they aren't defined at construction.

Comment: Thank you!   That resolved the link error however now Im stuck on how to use a method function.  I cannot seem to pass numerator and denominator successfully between functions.  however Im able to pass back r.numerator and r.denominator.  I need to capture all 4 values.  I was under the impression by doing what I had I would be able to pas back a value to numerator and denominator and to r.numerator and r.denominator.  I would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 5):

When you write this

```
Rational Result;
```

you instruct the compiler to create an object of type `Rational` using the default constructor (i.e. one that takes no arguments). You declared that constructor, but you did not provide its implementation.

You can add this code to fix the problem:

```
Rational::Rational() : numerator(0), denominator(1)
{
}
```

This wold make a `Rational` number of zero, with denominator of `1`.

Alternatively, you could change the declaration of the `Result` to avoid calling the default constructor, like this:

```
Rational Result(
    (numerator * r.denominator) + (r.numerator * denominator)
,   denominator * r.denominator
);
```

Comment: Thank you,  However now I cannot figure out how to make this work for all 4 inputs..  If I enter 1/2 and 1/4  I get a numerator value of 0 and a denominator value of 1 and a r.numerator value of 1 and a r.denominator of 2.  How doe i get the numerator & denominator to keep the inputed values?

Comment: @user2875114 You do not need `Rational r` inside `Rational::Input()`, because both `numerator` and `denominator` are there as member variables. Same goes for all other methods that do not return a value:  since the semantic is to modify the instance on which the method is called, the "result" is actually your `this` object; no separate result is needed.